# How can I test a class that uses DispatcherTimer?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, dispatcher, dispatchertimer

I've found a couple of Stack Overflow questions along with a couple of blog posts that already touch on this topic, but unfortunately none of them are meeting my needs. I'll just start with some sample code to show what I'd like to accomplish.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MyApp
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyTests
    {
        private int _value;

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task TimerTest()
        {
            _value = 0;
            var timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)};
            timer.Tick += IncrementValue;
            timer.Start();

            await Task.Delay(15);
            DispatcherUtils.DoEvents();
            Assert.AreNotEqual(0, _value);
        }

        private void IncrementValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _value++;
        } 
    }

    internal class DispatcherUtils
    {
        [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
        public static void DoEvents()
        {
            var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
            Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
        }

        private static object ExitFrame(object frame)
        {
            ((DispatcherFrame)frame).Continue = false;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine if, instead of using a DispatcherTimer, I use an ordinary Timer. But DispatcherTimer never fires. What am I missing? What do I need to get it to fire?

Comment: I think you would need to set the SynchronizationContext to an instance of DispatcherSynchronizationContext. Otherwise on the other side of the await you are on a new thread that will have a new dispatcher, which is not the one you want to process events for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's best if you can avoid `DispatcherTimer` in your system under test and use an abstraction instead (Rx has a nice one called `IScheduler`). This kind of abstraction allows you to explicitly control the flow of time in your unit tests, rather than making your tests conditional on CPU timings.

But if you are just interested in unit testing for now, then you'll need to create an STA thread that does message pumping *and* have a proper `Dispatcher` installed. All "run this code on the dispatcher" operations just wrap a delegate in a Win32 message, and if you don't have a Win32 message pumping loop *in* a `Dispatcher` (*before* creating the timer), then those messages won't be processed.

The easiest way to do this is to use `WpfContext` from [here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncCTPUtil):

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TimerTest()
{
  await WpfContext.Run(() =>
  {
    _value = 0;
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)};
    timer.Tick += IncrementValue;
    timer.Start();

    await Task.Delay(15);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(0, _value);
  });
}
```

Again, this kind of approach is substandard because it depends on timings. So if your antivirus gets upset and decides to inspect your unit test, it can spuriously fail. An abstraction like `IScheduler` enables reliable unit tests.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you so much for all the added detail.

Comment: I had to resort to this approach because I was working in a huge legacy code base where refactoring meant a huge regression risk.